# Basic interrupt for PIC16f887 on 44pinBoard

Tags: assembly, interrupt, pic, microchip

I'm trying to create a basic interrupt code on a PIC16F887 and I'm not sure why LED1 isn't lighting (to show that it has gone into interrupt) 
any help appreciated

```
#include <p16F887.inc>
__CONFIG    _CONFIG1, _LVP_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _BOR_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _CP_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT
__CONFIG    _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _BOR21V



org 0
goto    START

org 4
goto INT

 INT:        
LOOP:   bsf PORTD,1
            ;call    DELAY
            ;incf    PUSH_COUNT,f    ;increment PUSH_COUNT
           ; bcf     INTCON,INTF     ;clear int flag
       goto LOOP
            retfie

START:

 clrf    INTCON          ;clear INTCON register
 bsf     INTCON,INTE     ;enable external int on INT pin
 bsf     INTCON,GIE      ;enable global int

 bsf     STATUS,RP0  ; select Register Bank 1
 bcf     TRISD,0     ; make IO Pin RD0 an output
 movlw   0x01     ;set RB0 as input
 movwf   TRISB           ;move value to TRISB
 bcf     STATUS,RP0  ; back to Register Bank 0
 bsf     PORTD,0     ; turn on LED RD0 (DS0)
 goto     $          ; wait here



 end
```

Comment: Use MPLAB debugger to debug your program!

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is years late for the original poster but offered as help for anyone else reading this post.

The original code does not enable PORTB bit RB0 for digital I/O.
This is done by clearing ANSELH bit ANS12 to zero.

Here is code that does what the original poster requested:

```
;
; Project: 16F887_INT+LED
; File: main.asm
; Target: PIC16F887
; Assembler: MPASM v5.22
; Assembler mode: absolute
;
; Additional files:
;   p16F887.inc
;
; Description:
;
; Using DM164120-2 44-pin Demo board catch interrupt from SW1 and light DS0.
;
;                                               PIC16F887
;             +---------+            +---------+            +-----------+            +-----------+
;       <>  1 : RC7/RX  :      -- 12 : NC      :      <> 23 : RA4       :      -- 34 : NC        :
;  LED4 <-  2 : RD4     :      -- 13 : NC      :      <> 24 : RA5       :      <> 35 : RC1/T1OSI :
;  LED5 <-  3 : RD5     :      <> 14 : RB4     :      <> 25 : RE0       :      <> 36 : RC2       :
;  LED6 <-  4 : RD6     :      <> 15 : RB5     :      <> 26 : RE1       :      <> 37 : RC3       :
;  LED7 <-  5 : RD7     :  PGC <> 16 : RB6/PGC :      <> 27 : RE2       : LED0 <- 38 : RD0       :
;   GND ->  6 : VSS     :  PGD <> 17 : RB7/PGD :  5v0 -> 28 : VDD       : LED1 <- 39 : RD1       :
;   5v0 ->  7 : VDD     :  VPP -> 18 : RE3/VPP :  GND -- 29 : VSS       : LED2 <- 40 : RD2       :
;   SW1 ->  8 : RB0/INT :  POT -> 19 : RA0     :      <> 30 : RA7/OSC1  : LED3 <- 41 : RD3       :
;       <>  9 : RB1     :      <> 20 : RA1     :      <> 31 : RA6/OSC2  :      <> 42 : RC4       :
;       <> 10 : RB2     :      <> 21 : RA2     :      <> 32 : RC0/T1OSO :      <> 43 : RC5       :
;       <> 11 : RB3/PGM :      <> 22 : RA3     :      -- 33 : NC        :      <> 44 : RC6/TX    :
;             +---------+            +---------+            +-----------+            +-----------+
;                                                TQFP-44
;
    list p=16F887, n=0, c=255
    errorlevel -302         ; Suppress warning: Register in operand not in bank 0 

#include "p16F887.inc"
    __CONFIG    _CONFIG1, _LVP_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _BOR_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _CP_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT
    __CONFIG    _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _BOR21V
;
; Reset vector
    org     0
    goto    START
;
; Interrupt handler
;
; Note:
;   This is a bad implementation of an interrupt handler.
;   Does not save the interrupted context.
;   Expects that regieter bank 0 is always selected.
;   This only works in the very special case.
;   Do not think that this is good code.
;   You have been warned.
;   
    org     4
    bsf     PORTD,0         ; turn on LED RD0 (DS0)
    bcf     INTCON,INTF
    retfie
;
; Main application
START:
    clrf    INTCON          ; clear INTCON register
    bsf     INTCON,GIE      ; enable global int

    bsf     STATUS,RP0      ; select Register Bank 1
    bcf     TRISD,0         ; make IO Pin RD0 an output
    movlw   0x01            ; set RB0 as input
    movwf   TRISB           ; move value to TRISB
    bsf     STATUS,RP1      ; select Register Bank 3
    bcf     ANSELH,ANS12    ; Make RB0 a digital I/O pin
    bcf     STATUS,RP1      ; select Register Bank 1
    bcf     STATUS,RP0      ; back to Register Bank 0
    bcf     PORTD,0         ; turn off LED RD0 (DS0)
    bsf     INTCON,INTE     ; enable external int on INT pin
    goto    $               ; wait here

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You set PORTD.0 (`bcf TRISD,0`) as output but your ISR is modifying PORTD.1 (`bsf PORTD,1`)

Try `bsf PORTD,0`

Comment: Hi yes that was a silly mistake, thank you!
I now have the problem where it goes straight into the interrupt.
Any ideas?

Comment: You enabled the interrupt without first clearing the flag. If the flag was already enabled, the interrupt would immediately trigger. Since this is an external interrupt (i.e. triggered by some external event), I cannot help you with the why it may or may not be triggered other than to say that triggering is cause by a raising or falling(depending on INTEDG) edge on the INT pin.